# Azure DevOps - Multiple Azure Function Deployments Replaces Each Other in a Single Function App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, .net-5

I have 2 .NET 5 Azure Function Visual Studio projects . These 2 Functions to be deployed in a single Azure Function App.

I have 2 separate Build  Pipelines for each of the projects and have separate Release Pipelines as well in Azure DevOps. I am not using YAML for release pipelines but depends on DevOps UI to choose a new Release pipeline.

My issue is that whenever running the Release pipeline, the last Release overrides the existing Function in Azure Function App. So, I am not getting 2 Functions as expected under a single Azure Function App. Always the last release deployment exists in Azure. Why one release deployment overrides existing Functions, even though they are from different Release pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

In the MS documentation it states that if you perform a "Zip Deployment" to an Azure Function, it will always overwrite what is running on the Azure Function Service. I presume that the "Classic Pipeline" gives you the "Zip Deployment" option.

Link to MS Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops#deployment-methods

For the moment, I do have a ticket open at Microsoft on how to manage different apps on the same Azure Function service. I only want changes made to the specific app where there are code changes without impacting any other existing apps on the Azure Function. For now, I only had one troubleshooting session with no solution in sight. I will share more information once I have received a solution/workaround.

Comment: Any update on this?